# Check if customer is in the DynamoDB table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nosql, dynamodb-queries

I have written some code that queries a table. Now I'm adding exceptions to it.
I'm new to Python and DynamoDB, so the progress is slow and not necessarily in the correct direction.
I got stuck with the part where I check if the customer name entered through input() exists in a table or not.

```
        customer_name = input("Enter name:")
        try:
            response = table.get_item(
                TableName=table_name, Key={'customer': {'S': str(customer_name)}}
                )

        except ClientError:
            logger.info(f'The customer is not found.')
        else:
            response = table.query(
         # some code
            )
```

It keeps returning that the customer does not exist. I don't understand why. Is there a better way to check if customer is in the table?
There are quite few entries under each customer name, so ideally it should search until it hits the first record and return that it exists, but I have no idea how to implement this =(

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wrote that there are a few entries under each customer name you should read about how dynamoDB tables are build and how the getItem query works.

In short: You can only get an Item by its' Primary Key and this Primary Key must be unique (which highlights where you are wrong).

Now there are some workarounds since a Primary Key can consist out of a partition key and a sort key with which a search until you find the first record with a certain customer name is possible.

As a beginner however I would advice you to only have one entry per customer and query your customer by its' name. If you want to do it advanced read about the different types of keys and the local and global secondary indexes.